# How do you make sure in angular 2+ that clicking on a button whose route is the same as the current page reloads the page?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

The first question that I must answer, why would I complain about that. You are already there, right?

I have two reasons why I need a reload to take place, But, I'll only mention the first.

1) my user clicks on the link, he does not realize the link he chose is the same as the current page. His button clicks and does the wavy animation but nothing is carried out after that. User thinks the link is broken. But If the page were to reload, he would not take this as a flaw.

Is there anyway in angular to tell the router that if you are on /xyx and the user clicks on /xyz link, the app should reload.

Comment: try using this:  runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',  into the route decaration

Comment: Tried that, but made no diff.

Comment: {path: 'learning-plan/:action/:extras/:template', component: ManageLearningPlanComponent, runGuardsAndResolvers: "always"}, No luck!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this one?

```
if (url === window.location.href) {
    window.location.reload();
} else {
    this.router.navigate([url]);
}
```

Comment: Smart work arounds... But I think I will go with the `runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',`

Comment: this approach will do a full page reload which may take again some time depending on the application size

Comment: I realized it but the runGuardsAndRevolvers made no diff to me.